# FIleSystemWatcher monitoring hungs up

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystemwatcher, administration, orchestration

I`m trying to make a ftp orchestrator in PowerShell based on FileSystemWatcher from .Net which would then run other PowerShell script to process this file.

But I`ve faced problem when monitor unexepectedly hungs up, and no longer works ( should be logging it`s actions - has logging module).

I can`t find pattern because sometimes it can work for 3 days, sometimes after ~1 day, and recently it stopped after 40 mins of working.
Don`t think that it`s the case of amout of files processed, because my logs contain from 32 KB to 32 MB ; /.

I have default InternalBufferSize.

How to get information about what is the source of this problem?

How increase the verbosity of all components to know what is going on?

```
try {
        $fswObject = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher "$folderToMonitor", $eventData.matchingFileMask -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $eventData.includeSubdirectories; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,LastWrite'}
        $fswObject.EnableRaisingEvents = $True
        $sourceIdentifier = "$($sourceIdentifierId)_$($eventData.matchingFileMask)" # to make source identifier unique
        $existingSubscription = Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ( $existingSubscription ) {
            Write-LogWarn "($PID) Subscription '$($existingSubscription.SourceIdentifier)' exists, unregistering"
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier
        }
        Write-LogDebug "($PID) Registering watcher in '$folderToMonitor' for file matching $($eventData.matchingFileMask) with source identifier $sourceIdentifier"
        $dataToPass = New-Object PSObject -property @{
            matchingFileMask = $eventData.matchingFileMask;
            startProgram     = $eventData.startProgram.Trim();
            folderToMonitor  = $folderToMonitor
        }

        Register-ObjectEvent $fswObject $eventData.triggeringFileEvent -SourceIdentifier $sourceIdentifier -MessageData $dataToPass -Action {
            Param($fswObject = $fswObject)

            $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
            $fullname = $Event.MessageData.folderToMonitor + "\" + $name
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
            $object_type = (Get-Item $fullname).GetType().name -replace "Info", ""
            Write-LogInfo "($PID) [$object_type] '$fullname' was $changeType at $timeStamp for mask $($Event.MessageData.matchingFileMask)"
            if ( $Event.MessageData.startProgram -ne "" ) {
                $startProgram = $Event.MessageData.startProgram.split(" ")[0]
                $programParams = $Event.MessageData.startProgram.Substring( $startProgram.Length ).Trim()
                try {
                    # will start new parallel job
                } catch {
                    Write-LogError "($PID) Error when executing $PSScriptRoot\$startProgram $programParams $($Event.MessageData.folderToMonitor)\$name, error is '$Error'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend starting slow. Write a small script that contains only enough code for absolute minimum functionality and test incrementally.

Comment: Done this way, but everything is in 3 files now and about 500 loc. And haven't meet before this type of problems nor have now time to test code step by step to see if it will hung after 3 days...